# Ansible & Docker: Need to establish ssh session from Ansible container to Docker host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible, dockerfile, host

I have a docker-compose YAML file set up to build an Ansible container on the alpine:3.7 image, and 3 other Docker containers that will be managed by the Ansible container. I have been able to configure the inventory for the Ansible server in a way to use `ansible_connection=docker` for the other containers, but am not able to connect to the underlying Docker host machine from the Ansible container. (MacOS)

The problem is that we need to be able to communicate with the host for file transfers that the Ansible container would request as part of playbooks being executed there, but I'm not sure how to set up the host and/or container to achieve the proper connection. This is for a development environment, so it doesn't need to be ultra-secure, though I generally prefer best practices, even if the environment wouldn't necessarily call for it.

I've tried using a **local** connection type, but realized that Ansible resolves that as the machine that it is running on, which is the container. I've also attempted to look up how to create and share an SSH key between the host and container, but am not understanding the concept behind it and am not sure if the articles I've come across promote the best practice for sharing the keys and establishing communications. I was avoiding using `host.docker.internal` to resolve the host IP in the container as it is only recognized in Mac and Windows, and not in production mode (from what I've found online).

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  ansible:
    container_name: ansible
    build:
      context: ./ansible/
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKERBUILD}/ansible:/ansible
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - project-network
    extra_hosts:
      # Tried setting the gateway address for the subnet in the custom network as a host 
      # on the Ansible container, but still cannot connect: Connection refused on port 22.
      - dockerhost:172.55.0.1

  oracle11g:
    container_name: oracle11g
    build:
      context: ./oracle11g/
    environment:
      - ORACLE_PWD=oracle
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKERSHARE}/oracle11g/tmp:/tmp
    networks:
      - project-network

# OTHER CONTAINERS OMITTED FOR BREVITY.

networks:
  project-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.55.0.0/16
```

**Dockerfile (ansible container)**

```Dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.7

ENV ANSIBLE_VERSION 2.7.0
ARG ANSIBLE_SETUP_DIR=./setup
ARG ANSIBLE_ETC=/etc/ansible

 # Install missing dependencies
 # --------------------------------------------------------------------
ENV BUILD_PACKAGES \
  bash \
  curl \
  tar \
  openssh-client \
  sshpass \
  git \
  python \
  py-boto \
  py-dateutil \
  py-httplib2 \
  py-jinja2 \
  py-paramiko \
  py-pip \
  py-yaml \
  ca-certificates \
  docker

# Copy host file
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

RUN mkdir -p /etc/ansible/

COPY $ANSIBLE_SETUP_DIR/hosts $ANSIBLE_SETUP_DIR/ssh.config $ANSIBLE_ETC/


# Install Ansible
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

RUN set -x && \
    \
    echo "==> Adding build-dependencies..."  && \
    apk --update add --virtual build-dependencies \
      gcc \
      musl-dev \
      libffi-dev \
      openssl-dev \
      python-dev && \
    \
    echo "==> Upgrading apk and system..."  && \
    apk update && apk upgrade && \
    \
    echo "==> Adding Python runtime..."  && \
    apk add --no-cache ${BUILD_PACKAGES} && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install python-keyczar && \
    \
    echo "==> Installing Ansible..."  && \
    pip install ansible==${ANSIBLE_VERSION} && \
    \
    echo "==> Cleaning up..."  && \
    apk del build-dependencies && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    echo "==> Appending SSH config for host..." && \
    cat $ANSIBLE_ETC/ssh.config >> /root/.ssh/ssh_config && \
    rm -rf $ANSIBLE_ETC/ssh.config

ENV ANSIBLE_GATHERING smart
ENV ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING false
ENV ANSIBLE_RETRY_FILES_ENABLED false
ENV ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH /ansible/playbooks/roles
ENV ANSIBLE_SSH_PIPELINING True
ENV PYTHONPATH /ansible/lib
ENV PATH /ansible/bin:$PATH
ENV ANSIBLE_LIBRARY /ansible/library
ENV ANSIBLE_HOME=/ansible/
# In milliseconds, represents 9800+ years.
ENV INFINITY=2147483647d

WORKDIR ${ANSIBLE_HOME}
EXPOSE 22

# Keep container alive by issuing default entrypoint of "infinite" sleep.
ENTRYPOINT ["sleep", "2147483647d"]
```

**inventory ($ANSIBLE_SETUP_DIR/hosts)**

```
[host]
dockerhost

[docker-containers]
ansible ansible_connection=local
oracle11g ansible_connection=docker
```

I've seen a few articles on stackoverflow regarding communications *from* the host *to* the container, but relatively few for the reverse, and none that seemed to resolve this specific problem (to me, anyway). Hope someone has the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> ...and 3 other Docker containers that will be managed by the Ansible
>   container.

Docker containers are not meant to be managed in this way, running container images should be expected to be *immutable*, which is to say they are not expected to change once deployed.

Everything you need inside your running docker image should be managed by the container image build process, the environment variables, the mounted volumes, and the application running inside.

If you need to change something in a running container, a new image should be built and deployed.

Comment: This isn't exactly helpful; the ask wasn't to evaluate the implementation of the Docker containers, but how to communicate from the Ansible docker container to the host.

Comment: Docker is just a tool. If it solves a problem, it was the right tool. So using Docker against some best practice might be perfectly justified.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, i created an ansible-docker image to manage my home network, including the machine it is running on.

i use `docker run` for this, as i only want to run the container if i need to do something, afterwards it can be removed.

I came across this thread as i was having a similar issue, and i solved it by doing `docker rum --rm -it --network host`

So the solution should be, to add `--network host` in your docker-compose file.

hth